# SQL Server Configuration Manager: Error 0x800706be

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Running a computer with SQL Server 2012 Express installed.

Just installed SQL Server 2008 Express and updated to SP3. Also have installed SQL Server 2008 R2 Express and updated to its SP3.

- Opened SQL Server Configuration Manager, enabled "Named Pipes" and "TCP/IP" in SQLEXPRESS' Protocols, set TCP/IP Dynamic Ports = [null] and TCP/IP Port = 1433.
- Opened 'Services' via Start menu and restarted MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS.
- Opened SQL Server Configuration Manager and refreshed SQL Server Services, but it continues to read only "The remote procedure call failed. [0x800706be]"

I've read from *some* folks that its a issue of outdated drivers. Others, it seems, say it's just a matter of deleting SQL Server 2012, but none of that feels right.

I'm not sure what else to try at this point. I've never worked in SQL Server Configuration Manager or Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio before, let alone servers in general. I just want to be able to practice writing SQL queries for work using some unnamed software I brought home along with generic test data, and getting SQL Server working is step one in the installation process.

Comment: Few suggestions here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12619014/remote-procedure-call-failed-with-sql-server-2008-r2